# How to set selected by default with HTML5 datalist

Tags: html

With HTML  one can set the default selected item like this:

```
<option value="blaah" selected>
```

But how to do it with HTML5 and DataList select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had such a workaround that I added the default value into placeholder and then with the server-side language (I used PHP but you can do it with whatever you use) I check if the POST/GET is empty then it means default value.

Then I added into CSS:

```
::placeholder {  
    color: black; 
}
```

So now it also looks right and doesn't give the user a feel that it's a placeholder and something needs to be done.

Answer (score 4):

Not per se. Just set the `value` as normal.

```html
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" value="Strawberry" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```

Of course, clicks in the input will be filtered by the text already there, so users will have to delete it to get the list of suggestions back.

Comment: Yeah, tried that already but that's no good if you need to first delete the "value". Probably there's no such "non-hack" way to do it then. Check my own answer. Just came up with that workaround.